# Undefined reference to STL functions when building a lib statically, building to .so gives no errors

Tags: android, c++, linker, android-ndk

I've tried to build one of the libraries in my project to static lib - changed `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` to `include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)`. Now I get:

```
android-ndk-r6/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/list.tcc:103: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)
```

A thing to note: the reference is not from the library in question itself, but from another dynamic library that is linked to the library in question.

Any idea what's the problem here?

P. S. Dodged the problem by linking to STL dynamically, but would like to fix the problem in the first place and link statically.

P. P. S. This only happens with NDK r8.

Comment: Did you change the `Android.mk` of the module that includes the library from `INCLUDE_SHARED_LIBRARY` to `INCLUDE_STATIC_LIBRARY` or `INCLUDE_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARY`?

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong-: Good point! I have forgotten.